# How to make the hover affect when I move the cursor away from the button

Tags: css

Hey I am using some codeto create hover effect on a button but for some reason when I move the cursor away from the button the reversed affect doesn't happen and the button returns to normal immediately, how can I make the reversed effect when I move the cursor away from the button?
here is the code I used:

```
#sides:hover {
  background-color: rgb(122, 131, 251);
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 1);
  opacity: 75%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use transition-duration this way:

```
#sides {
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
}
```